# Eclipse CDT New Project Template - How to add a library

Tags: templates, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse CDT Indigo, there is a new feature that allows you to add new C/C++ template projects to the new project wizard. I've figured out how to do this successfully up to a point. I can create a basic project that just depends on simple source files but now I'd like to create a CPPUnit project to which I'd like to automatically add the CPPUnit library.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to achieve this end.  Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry I am late, but I just had the very same question for the very same problem. I have figured out a solution. It works for me, but I am well aware that it is probably not as general as hoped for. In your template.xml, you may want to add the following process:

```
<process type="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.AppendToMBSStringListOptionValues">
    <simple name="projectName" value= "$(projectName)"/>      
    <complex-array name="resourcePaths">
        <element>
            <simple name="id" value="gnu.cpp.link.option.libs" />
            <simple-array name="values">
                <element value="dl" />
                <element value="cppunit" />
            </simple-array>
            <simple name="path" value="" />
        </element>
    </complex-array>
</process>
```

The crucial part is to know where to put the two libraries `dl` and `cppunit`. The key `gnu.cpp.link.option.libs` is the correct one for the GNU compiler tool chain which is active on most Linux computers.

I have extracted the key name from the Eclipse plugin `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.gnu.ui_XXXXXXX`. You can find it at Eclipse's `plugins` folder. If you need the key for another toolset, I recommend opening the plugin.xml file. Here, you should search for the attribute `valueType="libs"`. The corresponding `id` is the key you need to manipulate in your process file.

If you also need to manipulate the library search path, search for `valueType="libPaths"`. This will lead you to the key `gnu.cpp.link.option.paths`. You can add additional entries to the list with a process similar to the one shown above.

Answer (score 4):

It is **AMAZING** how hard this stuff is to find. In addition to **plugin.xml** browsing, all the **templates** provide efficient ramp up on implementing these options:

**Source Reference**

- manual download: [Eclipse CDT Source Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/cdt/releases/kepler/sr2/cdt-master-8.3.0.zip)

**Templates to Browse**

- plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.gnu.ui_X.X.X.xxxxx.jar/templates/projecttemplates/

  - and then in each proj dir (e.g. '*HeloWorldCAnsiProject*') locate template.xml

**GNU C Options to Browse**

- plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.gnu.ui_X.X.X.xxxxx.jar/plugin.xml

**Example Implementation By Reverse-Engineering**

**Goal** - set 'Cross GCC Compiler' -> Optimization -> 'Other optimization flags'

1. create a dummy C project with no customization
2. open properties. set the target field manually. I set 'Other optimization flags' to 'COME_FIND_ME'

   [image]
3. open the .cproject file in an editor. search for COME_FIND_ME. here is what I found:

   ```
   <option id="gnu.c.compiler.option.optimization.flags.1380831355" superClass="gnu.c.compiler.option.optimization.flags" value="COME_FIND_ME" valueType="string"/>
   ```

   - it is then of type 'string' and 'id' gnu.c.compiler.option.optimization.flags.

   [image]
4. Search in the plugin.xml listed above for 'gnu.c.compiler.option.optimization.flags'. Here's what i found (on line 1120):

   ```
     <option
         name="%Option.Posix.Optimize.Flags"
         category="gnu.c.compiler.category.optimization"
         id="gnu.c.compiler.option.optimization.flags"
         valueType="string">
     </option>
   ```

   [image]
5. get outta this example project, and go back to your template.xml you want to add this to. we want to append here to default value, so lets do that. add:

   ```
   <process type="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.AppendToMBSStringOptionValue">
       <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)" />

       <complex-array name="resourcePaths">
           <element>
               <simple name="id" value="gnu.c.compiler.option.optimization.flags" />
               <simple name="value" value="-Omg_eclipse" />
               <simple name="path" value="" />
           </element>
       </complex-array>
   </process>
   ```

and that's it.

**Useful Links**

1. [Help - Eclipse Platform - How to register a project template with CDT](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/projectTemplateEngine/Howtoregistertemplates.html)
2. [Help - Eclipse Platform - Example template](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/projectTemplateEngine/exampletemplate.html)

**Notes**

Here are where the MBS append/set functions live:

- org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.source_X.X.X.xxxxx.jar/org/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/templateengine/processes

[image]

**Full Template File Example**

finally, here's a code snippet that may save you hours of scouring the internet. this template.xml creates a new project by copying over main.c, and setting three build options.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<template type="ProjTempl" version="1.0" supplier="stack_overflow" revision="1.0" author="Justin Reina"
    id="EXE" label="My C Project" description="set some stuff."help="help.html">

   <process type="org.eclipse.cdt.core.CreateSourceFolder">
        <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)"/>
        <simple name="path" value="bsp"/>
    </process>

    <process type="org.eclipse.cdt.core.AddFiles">  
        <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)"/>     
        <complex-array name="files">    
            <element>
                <simple name="source"      value = "main.c"/>
                <simple name="target"      value = "main.c"/>
                <simple name="replaceable" value = "true"  />
            </element>
        </complex-array>
    </process>

    <process type="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.AppendToMBSStringListOptionValues">
        <simple name="projectName" value= "$(projectName)"/>      
        <complex-array name="resourcePaths">
            <element>
                <simple name="id" value="gnu.c.link.option.libs" />
                <simple-array name="values">
                    <element value="corestuff" />
                    <element value="utilstuff" />
                </simple-array>
                <simple name="path" value="" />
            </element>
        </complex-array>
    </process>

    <process type="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.AppendToMBSStringOptionValue">
        <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)" />

        <complex-array name="resourcePaths">
            <element>
                <simple name="id" value="gnu.c.compiler.option.optimization.flags" />
                <simple name="value" value="-Omg_eclipse" />
                <simple name="path" value="" />
            </element>
        </complex-array>
    </process>

    <process type="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.SetMBSBooleanOptionValue">
        <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)" />

        <complex-array name="resourcePaths">
            <element>
                <simple name="id" value="gnu.c.link.option.nostdlibs" />
                <simple name="value" value="true" />
                <simple name="path" value="" />
            </element>
        </complex-array>
    </process>
</template>
```

To the Eclipse Foundation; next time can I just pay you a half-day's salary for you to give me this information???

Comment: Is there a process for setting drop-downs? I'm working on one of these and have managed to get the various libraries, includes, and miscellaneous options set, but I have a drop-down I want to set and can't figure out how.

Comment: Also, I did the export process twice and noticed there are now two jars - is there a way to uninstall old versions? Just nuke the jar or are other files modified?