# Eclipse CDT get GCC options from code

Tags: gcc, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am working on an Eclipse Plugin that among other things must check which compiler options are set in the current C project.
Basically, I want to access the Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C Compiler -> All options field.

I have searched how to access it, but I haven't found a way to do it.
I tried to acces it via the preferences like in the following code :

```
    IEclipsePreferences root = Platform.getPreferencesService().getRootNode();
```

I can access the preferences of my plugin this way, but not those of the C project.

Does anyone know a way to do it ? I don't need to change the compiler options, just to know which flags are set.

**UPDATE:** I have found a solution.

```
    IResourceInfo info = getResourceInfo(translationUnit, description);
    ITool tools[] = info.getTools();
        for (ITool t : tools) {
            if (t.getName().compareToIgnoreCase("GCC C Compiler") == 0) {
                try {
                    //Finally the field I was looking for
                    String commandLine = t.getToolCommandFlagsString(getProject().getFullPath(), null);

                } catch (BuildException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

I can then parse the string, not ideal but it works.
I got the getResourceInfo() function from this post : [How do I programmatically change the Eclipse CDT tool settings for a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061538/how-do-i-programmatically-change-the-eclipse-cdt-tool-settings-for-a-file)

So, thanks justinmreina for the answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your traversing down a dark and lonely road, my friend :). but a fun one, nonetheless.

**Setting Options on a Custom Toolchain/Tool**

Here is an example where someone attempted to programmatically set the options of the GNU tools/toolchains:

- [Stack Overflow: How do I programmatically change the Eclipse CDT tool settings for a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061538/how-do-i-programmatically-change-the-eclipse-cdt-tool-settings-for-a-file)

*and here is that same author's background thread on solving it:

- [Eclipse Forum: How do I programmatically change the Eclipse CDT tool settings for a file?](http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/How-do-I-programmatically-change-the-Eclipse-CDT-tool-settings-for-a-file-td164231.html)

What he did here will get you to your resolution. I'd suggest browsing the plugin.xml of org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuild.gnu.ui first though. Focus on the toolchains, tools and their options.

**Finding the Options of the GNU C Toolchain(s)/Tool(s)**

Also, here is a useful post I put up awhile back on 'finding the dang options in a GNU C Project'. Not the exact OP's question, but the answer is relevant to your question.

- [Stack Overflow: Eclipse CDT New Project Template - How to add a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711056/eclipse-cdt-new-project-template-how-to-add-a-library/22120948#22120948)

**Conclusion**

I strongly doubt you'll find an answer <10 lines of code, even to set the '-v' flag for the Compiler... If you do find a simple result, I'd suggest posting it here as a followup.

Best of luck!

**EDIT**: I've been gnawing at this for awhile now, because I recently stumbled/failed over it. Here is how to set the options from code.

```
//assumptions
//#1 project  is [0] in workspace
//#2 compiler is [2] in workspace

//get project
IProject proj = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("hello_world");

//get <storageModule moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings">
IManagedBuildInfo info = ManagedBuildManager.getBuildInfo(proj);

//get <storageModule moduleId="cdtBuildSystem">
IManagedProject sub_info = info.getManagedProject();

//get <configuration name="Debug">
IConfiguration config = sub_info.getConfigurations()[0];

//get <toolChain>
IToolChain toolchain = config.getToolChain();

//get <tool name="GCC C Compiler">
ITool tool = toolchain.getTools()[2];

//get <option>
IOption option = tool.getOptionBySuperClassId("gnu.c.compiler.option.misc.other");

//----append new flag----//
String new_opt_value = option.getValue() + " -mySuperFlag";

//-----store it----//
ManagedBuildManager.setOption(config, tool, option, new_opt_value);
ManagedBuildManager.saveBuildInfo(proj, true);
```

**Notes**
- once you start viewing this operation as an 'Eclipse Resource', the methodology becomes (somewhat...) clear
- each object call down to access a field is just accessing another section within the XML schema of the .cproject resource

Hope this helps!

Comment: How to add -mmachine-option to eclipse?